# Should "of" be added in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Do you read of what you have collected?

Often I hear people say `of what you said`, `of what you did`...etc. So should I add `of` to the sentence above?

Comment: I'm afraid there are a few words that shouldn't be there. I'm not sure what you're sentence means; could you re-word it?

Comment: @ashlee It means `Do you read the stuff (books, comics, etc.) you have collected?`

Comment: Why "of"? Why not "about"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Of" is out of place here but the rest of the sentence is also worded unusually.

I might ask,

> Do you read your collection?

or even better was your 2nd example:

> Do you read the books you have collected?

Your examples of `of what you said` and `of what you did` wouldn't apply here, and I can't think of many cases where they would.  Perhaps,

> Sometimes I think of what you said.
>
> I understood all of what you said.
>
> Tell me the story of what you did.
>
> Are you ashamed of what you did?